# How to run a php code using json_decode?

Tags: php, json

I am learning to use `json_decode`. I want to try out some php code snippet using this, but I don't want to setup whole web service kind of system using web server,html etc etc..

Can I run some standalone php code on linux and see its output?

Comment: You can. Try `php -f filename.php`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP has a [command line interface](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php)

```
php myScript.php
```

(Note that many Linux distributions have separate packages for mod_php and php cli, so you might need to install it before you can use it)

Comment: In many cases, when I run php file.php, I just get the dump of file.php..It doesn't run..What does it mean? if the file.php is bad, is it the expected behaviour etc..?

Comment: @p2pnode — PHP is a template language. Code must appear between `<?php` and `?>` to be executed instead of passed through.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
Try a example from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).
Save it as *json.php* (or so) and run it on the console. (if you have installed php (`which php` will help))

go to the folder you saved the file and run:

```
php json.php
```

that's it.
The output will shown in the stdout (the console).

Comment: In many cases, when I run php file.php, I just get the dump of file.php..It doesn't run..What does it mean? if the file.php is bad, is it the expected behaviour etc..?

Comment: maybe the -f option will help (see the comment by Pekka)... php -f file.php ... the man said: Parse and execute file

Comment: @SebastianThiele — `-f` is optional, see the docs I linked to in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have PHP installed at your system at all you might want to install it and the CLI as well.
For example on Ubuntu like systems it is done by:
sudo apt-get install php5-common php5-cli 
For other systems see [PHP Installation on Unix systems](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.php)
Then  you can make a little PHP file:

```
    <?php
        echo "Hello, World !!!" . PHP_EOL;
```

and save it as hello.php
then run it by

```
        php -f hello.php
```

For the little code snippets like that you might want try this

```
        php -r 'echo "Hello, World !!!" . PHP_EOL'
```

this should output the same result;

It can be used instaed of a  calculator for tasks like:

```
    php -r 'echo pow(2,3) * 2 . PHP_EOL;'
```

which outputs 16

as of json, try with

```
    echo json_encode(array("foo" => "bar"));
```

which gives

```
    {"fff":"dfsf"}
```

and

```
    print_r( json_decode('{"fff":"dfsf"}') );
```

which outputs

```
    stdClass Object
    (
        [fff] => dfsf
    )
```